# Javascript, save API response to manipulate with other buttons on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, so all constructive criticism is appreciated. When a user loads the page, I have some JavaScript that calls an API and gets a Json response. With this response I create the table body. For each column header in the table I have a button icon that represent sorting the column. When the user clicks this button, it will call the API again, sort the data and then create & replace the table body. Clicking the button again with call the API, sort the data in the opposite direction and create & replace the table.

I am struggling to implement it so that when the user clicks on the filter button, it doesn't call the API every time, but instead uses the data that is returned when the user first loads the page. I feel like my current implementation is performance heavy as the table can range from zero rows to 2000 rows.

I also believe the switch statement is a bit heavy. If there is a more efficient way of performing the process it would be greatly appreciated.

**html**

```html
...
<th scope="col" style="width: 03%;" >
  <h5>#</h5>
  <button class="btn-icon sort filterDesc" id="sort-number" onclick='getData("number")'>
    <img class="icon" src="{% static 'img/icons/sort.png' %}">
  </button>
</th>
<th scope="col" style="width: 25%;" class="">
  <h5>Name</h5>
  <button class="btn-icon sort" id="sort-name" onclick='getData("name")'>
    <img class="icon" src="{% static 'img/icons/sort.png' %}">
  </button>
</th>
...
```

**javascript**

```js
var send_data = {}
var setCode = ''

$(document).ready(function () { 
  getData(); 
})

function appendLeadingZeroes(n) { if (n <= 9) { return "0" + n; } return n }

function getData(sort) {
  let url = $('#sets-individual-page').attr("url")
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    data: send_data,
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (result) {
      putData(result, sort);
    },
    error: function (response) {
    }
  });
}

function putData(result, sort) {
  setCode = (result[0]['code']).toLowerCase()

  /* Sorting Functionality */
  function compareDesc(el1, el2, index) {return el1[index] == el2[index] ? 0 : (el1[index] > el2[index] ? -1 : 1);}
  function compareAsc(el1, el2, index) {return el1[index] == el2[index] ? 0 : (el1[index] < el2[index] ? -1 : 1);}

  switch (sort) {
    case 'number':
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("sort");
      for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].id === "sort-number") {
          if (elements[i].classList.contains("filterDesc")) {
            elements[i].classList.remove("filterDesc");
            elements[i].classList.add("filterAsc");
            result[0]['cards'].sort(function(el2, el1){return compareAsc(el1, el2, "number")});
          } else {
            elements[i].classList.remove("filterAsc");
            elements[i].classList.add("filterDesc");
            result[0]['cards'].sort(function(el2, el1){return compareDesc(el1, el2, "number")});
          }
        } else {
           elements[i].classList.remove("filterDesc");
           elements[i].classList.remove("filterAsc");
        }
      }
      break;
    case 'name':
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("sort");
      for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].id === "sort-name") {
          if (elements[i].classList.contains("filterDesc")) {
            elements[i].classList.remove("filterDesc");
            elements[i].classList.add("filterAsc");
            result[0]['cards'].sort(function(el2, el1){return compareAsc(el1, el2, "name")});
          } else {
            elements[i].classList.remove("filterAsc");
            elements[i].classList.add("filterDesc");
            result[0]['cards'].sort(function(el2, el1){return compareDesc(el1, el2, "name")});
          }
        } else {
           elements[i].classList.remove("filterDesc");
           elements[i].classList.remove("filterAsc");
        }
      }
      break;
    case 'type':
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("sort");
      for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].id === "sort-type") {
          if (elements[i].classList.contains("filterDesc")) {
            elements[i].classList.remove("filterDesc");
            elements[i].classList.add("filterAsc");
            result[0]['cards'].sort(function(el2, el1){return compareAsc(el1, el2, "type")});
          } else {
            elements[i].classList.remove("filterAsc");
            elements[i].classList.add("filterDesc");
            result[0]['cards'].sort(function(el2, el1){return compareDesc(el1, el2, "type")});
          }
        } else {
           elements[i].classList.remove("filterDesc");
           elements[i].classList.remove("filterAsc");
        }
      }
      break;
    case 'rarity':
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("sort");
      for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].id === "sort-rarity") {
          if (elements[i].classList.contains("filterDesc")) {
            elements[i].classList.remove("filterDesc");
            elements[i].classList.add("filterAsc");
            result[0]['cards'].sort(function(el2, el1){return compareAsc(el1, el2, "rarity")});
          } else {
            elements[i].classList.remove("filterAsc");
            elements[i].classList.add("filterDesc");
            result[0]['cards'].sort(function(el2, el1){return compareDesc(el1, el2, "rarity")});
          }
        } else {
           elements[i].classList.remove("filterDesc");
           elements[i].classList.remove("filterAsc");
        }
      }
      break;
    case 'convertedManaCost':
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("sort");
      for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].id === "sort-convertedManaCost") {
          if (elements[i].classList.contains("filterDesc")) {
            elements[i].classList.remove("filterDesc");
            elements[i].classList.add("filterAsc");
            result[0]['cards'].sort(function(el2, el1){return compareAsc(el1, el2, "convertedManaCost")});
          } else {
            elements[i].classList.remove("filterAsc");
            elements[i].classList.add("filterDesc");
            result[0]['cards'].sort(function(el2, el1){return compareDesc(el1, el2, "convertedManaCost")});
          }
        } else {
           elements[i].classList.remove("filterDesc");
           elements[i].classList.remove("filterAsc");
        }
      }
      break;
    case 'colors':
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("sort");
      for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].id === "sort-colors") {
          if (elements[i].classList.contains("filterDesc")) {
            elements[i].classList.remove("filterDesc");
            elements[i].classList.add("filterAsc");
            result[0]['cards'].sort(function(el2, el1){return compareAsc(el1, el2, "colors")});
          } else {
            elements[i].classList.remove("filterAsc");
            elements[i].classList.add("filterDesc");
            result[0]['cards'].sort(function(el2, el1){return compareDesc(el1, el2, "colors")});
          }
        } else {
           elements[i].classList.remove("filterDesc");
           elements[i].classList.remove("filterAsc");
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
  }

  /* Card - Large - Card Details */
  let row;
  if (result[0]["cards"].length > 0) {
    $("#card-listings").html("");
    $.each(result[0]["cards"], function (a, b) {
      let manaCostString = '';
      (b.manaCostList).forEach(i => manaCostString += "<img class=\"symbol\" src=\"/static/img/symbology/" + i + ".png\">");

      row = "<tr>"
        + "<td class=\"text-end\">" + b.number + "</td>"
        + "<td class=\"\">"
        +   "<span class=\"btn-icon btn-icon-primary\"><img class=\"icon\" src=\"/static/img/icons/image.png\"></span>"
        +   "<span class=\"large\" id=\"large\"><img class=\"large-image\" src=\"" + b.imageUri + "\" height=\"500\"></span>"
        +   b.name
        + "</td>"
        + "<td class=\"\">" + b.type + "</td>"
        + "<td class=\"\">" + (b.rarity).replace(/\b\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase()) + "</td>"
        + "<td class=\"\">" + Math.round(b.convertedManaCost) + "</td>"
        + "<td class=\"\">" + manaCostString + "</td>"
        + "<td class=\"standard\">"
        +   "<div class=\"inventory\">"
        +     "<span class=\"btn-icon btn-icon-primary\" onclick=\"updateCard(this)\" data-type=\"minus\" data-card-id=\"" + b.id + "\" data-card-type=\"standard\"><img class=\"icon\" src=\"/static/img/icons/minus.png\"></span>"
        +     "<input type=\"number\" class=\"page-input-inventory\" onchange=\"updateCard(this)\" autocomplete=\"off\" tabindex=\"1\" value=\"" + (b.inventory[0] == undefined ? '0' : b.inventory[0]['standard']) + "\" data-card-id=\"" + b.id + "\" data-card-type=\"standard\">"
        +     "<span class=\"btn-icon btn-icon-primary\" onclick=\"updateCard(this)\" data-type=\"plus\" data-card-id=\"" + b.id + "\" data-card-type=\"standard\"><img class=\"icon\" src=\"/static/img/icons/plus.png\"></span>"
        +   "</div>"
        +   "<div class=\"text-danger float-right\">£" + (Math.random() * (15.00 - 5.00) + 5.00).toFixed(2) + "</div>"
        +   "<div class=\"text-danger float-right\">+12%</div>"
        + "</td>"
        + "<td class=\"foil\">"
        +   "<div class=\"inventory\">"
        +     "<span class=\"btn-icon btn-icon-primary\" onclick=\"updateCard(this)\" data-type=\"minus\" data-card-id=\"" + b.id + "\" data-card-type=\"foil\"><img class=\"icon\" src=\"/static/img/icons/minus.png\"></span>"
        +     "<input type=\"number\" class=\"page-input-inventory\" onchange=\"updateCard(this)\" autocomplete=\"off\" tabindex=\"2\" value=\"" + (b.inventory[0] == undefined ? '0' : b.inventory[0]['foil']) + "\" data-card-id=\"" + b.id + "\" data-card-type=\"foil\">"
        +     "<span class=\"btn-icon btn-icon-primary\" onclick=\"updateCard(this)\" data-type=\"plus\" data-card-id=\"" + b.id + "\" data-card-type=\"foil\"><img class=\"icon\" src=\"/static/img/icons/plus.png\"></span>"
        +   "</div>"
        +   "<div class=\"text-danger\">£" + (Math.random() * (25.00 - 15.00) + 15.00).toFixed(2) + "</div>"
        +   "<div class=\"text-danger\">+12%</div>"
        + "</td>"
        + "</tr>"
      $("#card-listings").append(row);
    });
  } else {
    $("#card-listings").html("<tr><td colspan=\"7\"><div class=\"loading\"><span class=\"loading-text\">No Cards Found</span></div></td></tr>");
  }
}
```

Comment: You could save the results loaded from server into browser's local storage, then you could perform any actions on this data and display it like you want.

Comment: Ill have a look into that.